# What are the known Android keypad commands (dialer codes)?

Tags: dialer-codes

There are a lot of different keypad commands in Android. What are the known ones?

Some of them are listed here :

- `*#*#checkin#*#*`:  Phones home to check for updates.
- `*#*#info#*#*`: Enters a detailed phone information menu.
- `*#*#1472365#*#*`: Access to the GPS config menu (useful for patching [Galaxy S GPS failure](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/how-can-i-fix-the-gps-on-my-samsung-galaxy-s))

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37020/what-are-androids-secret-telephony-codes

Comment: Hey, do these still work in newer versions of Android? I just tried on a Moto X (2013) running 4.4.4 and a N6 on 5.0 without luck. On the Moto X, the commands are at least 'accepted' in that they disappear from the dialer when a complete one is entered, but even this part doesn't happen on the N6. EDIT: None of the commands appear to have any effect on the Moto X except for `#*#checkin#*#` which, after a moment, does display a 'checkin succeeded' notification.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This [page](http://www.askvg.com/google-android-hidden-secret-codes/) has a good listing of keypad commands.

Here is the post:

---

```
*#*#4636#*#*
```

This code can be used to get some interesting information about your phone and battery. It shows following 4 menus on screen:

- Phone information
- Battery information
- Battery history
- Usage statistics

---

```
*#*#7780#*#*
```

This code can be used for a factory data reset. It'll remove following things:

- Google account settings stored in your phone
- System and application data and settings
- Downloaded applications

It'll NOT remove:

- Current system software and bundled applications
- SD card files e.g. photos, music files, etc.

PS: Once you give this code, you get a prompt screen asking you to click on "Reset phone" button. So you get a chance to cancel your operation.

---

```
*2767*3855#
```

Think before you give this code. This code is used for factory format. It'll remove all files and settings including the internal memory storage. It'll also reinstall the phone firmware.

PS: Once you give this code, there is no way to cancel the operation unless you remove the battery from the phone. So think twice before giving this code.

---

```
*#*#34971539#*#*
```

This code is used to get information about phone camera. It shows following 4 menus:

- Update camera firmware in image (Don't try this option)
- Update camera firmware in SD card
- Get camera firmware version
- Get firmware update count

**WARNING**: Never use the first option otherwise your phone camera will stop working and you'll need to take your phone to service center to reinstall camera firmware.

---

```
*#*#7594#*#*
```

This one is my favorite one. This code can be used to change the "End Call / Power" button action in your phone. Be default, if you long press the button, it shows a screen asking you to select any option from Silent mode, Airplane mode and Power off.

You can change this action using this code. You can enable direct power off on this button so you don't need to waste your time in selecting the option.

---

```
*#*#273283*255*663282*#*#*
```

This code opens a File copy screen where you can backup your media files e.g. Images, Sound, Video and Voice memo.

---

```
*#*#197328640#*#*
```

This code can be used to enter into Service mode. You can run various tests and change settings in the service mode.

---

**WLAN, GPS and Bluetooth Test Codes:**

`*#*#232339#*#*` OR `*#*#526#*#*` OR `*#*#528#*#*` - WLAN test (Use "Menu" button to start various tests)

`*#*#232338#*#*` - Shows WiFi MAC address

`*#*#1472365#*#*` - GPS test

`*#*#1575#*#*` - Another GPS test

`*#*#232331#*#*` - Bluetooth test

`*#*#232337#*#` - Shows Bluetooth device address

---

```
*#*#8255#*#*
```

This code can be used to launch GTalk Service Monitor.

---

**Codes to get Firmware version information:**

`*#*#4986*2650468#*#*` - PDA, Phone, H/W, RFCallDate

`*#*#1234#*#*` - PDA and Phone

`*#*#1111#*#*` - FTA SW Version

`*#*#2222#*#*` - FTA HW Version

`*#*#44336#*#*` - PDA, Phone, CSC, Build Time, Changelist number

---

**Codes to launch various Factory Tests:**

`*#*#0283#*#*` - Packet Loopback

`*#*#0*#*#*` - LCD test

`*#*#0673#*#*` OR `*#*#0289#*#*` - Melody test

`*#*#0842#*#*` - Device test (Vibration test and BackLight test)

`*#*#2663#*#*` - Touch screen version

`*#*#2664#*#*` - Touch screen test

`*#*#0588#*#*` - Proximity sensor test

`*#*#3264#*#*` - RAM version

Comment: I tried some of the above commands with a HTC Incredible and none of them worked.  Is is just me, or are these fake?

Comment: Many of these doesn't work in Samsung (Pie) either.

Answer (score 16):

Here are the standard vanilla codes that should work across all devices:

A quick grep through the source code revealed these secret dial codes (for **Android 4.1**):

- **4636** (show debug info in apps/Settings)
- **8351**, **8350** (start/stop voice call debug logging or so in apps/VoiceDialer)
- **36245** (debug email in apps/Email)
- **8477** (? in apps/Protips)
- **225** (debug calendar in providers/CalendarProvider)

I did also check all available Google Apps from http://goo.im/gapps (Versions 2.2-4.2 w/o 3.x):

**Android 2.2** and **2.3**:

- **8255** (Google Talk)
- **46**, **7867**, **2432546** (GoogleServicesFramework)

**Android 4.0**, **4.1** and **4.2 Jelly Bean**:

- **8255**, **46**, **7867**, **947322243**, **2432546** (GoogleServicesFramework)
- **759**  (GooglePartnerSetup)

Note:
This functionality is realized via regular broadcast intents and filters, i.e. any app that wants to can define their own code and subscribe to those broadcasts. Also note, that the above code are only the visible open sourced part (CyanogenMod here), and Google Apps (which I did unpack and then scan). If you're interested in doing it yourself, unpack them with apktool and grep through their AndroidManifest.xml files for this way):

`egrep -r --include=\*xml SECRET_CODE\|android:host=\"\[0-9\] .`

It will find occurences in AndroidManifest.xml:

> ```
>     <receiver android:name=".checkin.CheckinService$SecretCodeReceiver">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />
>             <data android:scheme="android_secret_code" android:host="2432546" />
>         </intent-filter>
> ```

Comment: Here's another [linky](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=932919)

Answer (score 4):

There is an free app "SGS Tools" on the market which gives you all the collection of commands.

Comment: I assume many of those are Galaxy S specific or even Captivate specific, though?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunaltely, all Android devices will have a different set of secret codes.
Some of them are specific to some devices, some others aren't.
Secret Codes are generally defined by the applications installed on the device.

If you want to have a valid list of secret codes available on your device, you should use an automated secret codes crawler. Then you can search online for it's meaning.

I recently developped an Open Source app that crawls AndroidManifest.xml files on your device to found secret codes, and allows you to execute the secret codes available on your device.
You can get it on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.simon.marquis.secretcodes) or on the GitHub repository [Android-Secret Codes](https://github.com/SimonMarquis/Android-SecretCodes).

Comment: Uh-huuu... Are you now answering *all* our secret-code questions with this answer? ;) Will you apply the updates I've pointed to in the first place to all of them as well? #D Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

The code `*#*#4636#*#*` will not work on some Samsung devices; even with ADB, you don't have access to the menu.

However, there is a work-around with root access. Just type the following in a terminal on your phone and the hidden testing menu should appear:

```
su -c "am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.TestingSettings"
```

It may be easier through my app [Root Essentials](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superthomaslab.rootessentials) that can do this and more. You can find that test menu under "Device Info".

Comment: Sorry, while this answer is useful on its own, I'm afraid it doesn't really answer this specific question... This answer might be more suitable for other questions that asking about this issue instead.