# What special phone numbers can be used to display (hidden) info on Android phones?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, dialer-codes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you know other Android keypad commands ?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1468/do-you-know-other-android-keypad-commands)

In another post someone mentioned the special phone number `#*#4636#*#` to list CPU specific information.

I would like to ask you to list such **special phone numbers** in this post.

Mind you, I am *not looking for a list on a web page* (I'm sure that such a list is available somewhere).

I am looking for **special numbers you actually used yourself**, so you can vouch for the fact that they actually work.

Please mention your phone, because I can imagine some of them are phone specific, no ?

Comment: See also this previous question Do you know other Android keypad commands? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1468/do-you-know-other-android-keypad-commands

Comment: @GATHrawn: I searched the website for something like that, but obviously used the wrong search words :)  Nevertheless, I specifically ask for commands the writer has used. Not some sort of web site with a list of commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm running 2.1 Eclair on a Samsung Spica.

Well... the universal *#06# will display your IMEI - always a good idea to store this in a safe offline place in case your device is misplaced / stolen.

```
*#*#7780#*#*
```

will take you a screen where you can Factory Reset your device - you need to press an additional button to confirm or BACK to exit.

> `*#*#7594#*#*`

will show you Shutdown App configuration - you can choose to have the device power off directly instead of showing the menu for Airplane Mode / Power Off etc. when you long-press the power button. There's also an option for keeping the LCD on during the duration of a call - also useful to some people!

> `*#*#197328640#*#*`

shows a SERVICE MENU where different diagnostics can be carried out.

> `*#*#526#*#* OR *#*#528#*#*`

takes you to a WLAN test screen where you can check Transmit (TX) and Receive (RX) capabilities - press MENU for options.

> `*#*#0*#*#*`

LCD test

> `*#*#0842#*#*`

Vibration test

Naturally, some of these may be specific to certain device models only.