# How to use a Droid 2 without Verizon service activation

Tags: motorola-droid-2, activation

I purchased an old Droid 2 with a clean ESN today, rooted it, installed Droid2Bootstrap, loaded Monster_D2_2.3.2_4.5.153 onto the sdcard, cleaned the cache, wiped the data, rebooted into recovery, loaded the new images, rebooted. Came back up just fine.

Now, here is a problem you may not have experienced before. I am not a Verizon customer. Just wanted the phone to develops Apps and play with.

How can I get past the phone number activation requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're rooted, you might be able to bypass activation permanently by [killing the Phone dialer app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7133/how-do-i-turn-off-the-cellular-radio-without-disabling-bluetooth/7223#7223). This involves removing (or renaming) `Phone.apk`. I can at least confirm that this works on a Droid 1. Definitely make sure you have a [backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/what-is-the-right-way-to-backup-my-whole-phone) made prior to editing your system this way.

You can rename `Phone.apk` with an app like [Root Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer), or with the terminal app by mounting the system partition as rewritable. This also works if you've set up SSH:

```
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
cd /system/app
mv Phone.apk Phone.apk.old
pm uninstall Phone.apk
```

That disables the CDMA adapter and gets rid of the activation screen that always comes up on boot. It should also save you a little battery life too, since it's one less app, and one less adapter turned on. You might get an error when you rename the file, but after rebooting (forcefully, if necessary) everything should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

from [Droid Forums](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/tech-issues-bug-reports-suggestions/14594-droid-activation.html) To bypass activation:

- Reboot the phone, when the green android shows
- Tap top left
- Tap top right
- Tap bottom right
- Tap bottom left

Must be done every time you power on the phone

Comment: That's bizarre.

Comment: Tell me about it!  Although, funny enough the GPS NAV override on my Toyota Highlander is similar enough to make me think the programmer moved on to the droid

Comment: If you flash CyanogenMod it should bypass this. Or at least on my g1 it prevents the SIM card requiement, but I would figure it would be the same for CDMA phones on CM

Comment: err never mind last comment, I re read saw that it is a droid 2

Comment: Any idea how to do this is the right 1/2 inch of the screen doesn't respond to input?

Comment: Nevermind. For those that have this problem (I replaced my phone because of it), this also works in landscape mode, and the unresponsive screen area is most of the notification bar.

Comment: incidentally, for anyone with a Droid Pro, this also works on that device.

Comment: Is there an app for that? [According to that saying, there is, but really, there should be an app for that if there isn't.] I bought a Droid off of eBay and it's requesting for me to activate with Verizon... I don't want to do this every time. **Update: Found another way. Look at my answer.**

Answer (score 0):

Found another way to do this besides Noah's answer:

> simply touch the android, and select skip activation.

~ [Android Central Forums](http://forums.androidcentral.com/other-sony-android-phones/88122-bypass-activation.html) (Brought to you by Google and Chrome Browser)

---

I haven't tested this out yet, so let me know if it doesn't work so I can take this down and it isn't a nuisance.