# How can I save keypad command numbers like `*#*#4636#*#*` to my contact list?

Tags: contacts, dialer-codes

I learned from a previous question of mine that Android has got several system numbers, or "[keypad commands](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1468/do-you-know-other-android-keypad-commands)," which produce all kinds of information or invoke a system mode.

As example: one of them is `*#*#4636#*#*` ( *which produces all kinds of usage statistics* ).

**How can I save these number to my contacts list ?**

Or is there some **other way** that I can create a **short cut** to enter these numbers ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save it as contact; then when you want to use it -> navigate to it; and choose edit before sending.

Comment: +1 - works with the HTC Dialer

Comment: Hadn't thought of the `edit` part , great thinking. Thanks. Works on a Samsung Galaxy S.

Comment: "edit before..." then sending didn't work on my Moto One Action. I had to copy the code to clipboard and manually paste it into the dialer.