# What does the *#*#4636#*#* dialer code do?

Tags: dialer-codes

Has anyone tried the `*#*#4636#*#*` or `*#*#7780#*#*` dialer codes on HTC phones? They're not working for me.

Secondly, what does it show, means what kind of information? Is it safe to run on brand new phone?

Comment: What happens when you try the dialer code? In what sense is it not working?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to accomplish? It seems odd to be tinkering with secret star codes without a goal in mind already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I have a Samsung Galaxy S and the `*#*34636#*#*` does actually work.

It gives all sorts of statistics.

You might read my following question: [regarding this exact number and contact lists](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8155/how-can-i-save-keypad-command-numbers-like-4636-to-my-contact-list).

**-- EDIT --**

Sorry, didn't see the HTC phones bit. Just noticed the 'Samsung-Galaxy-tab' tag, and thought you were talking about the Samsung Galaxy S phone.

The part about the statistics , is ok , though.

On my phone.

- Phone information
- Battery information
- Battery history
- Usage statistics ( I was very interested in this option )
- Wifi information

Usage statistics

- Usage time
- Launch count

Comment: what sort of statistics?

Comment: @I-M-JM : see my edits

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're dialing it right? I just dialed wrong twice in a row (`*#*#` not `#*#*`) and got this error: "Connection problem or invalid MMI code." When I dial it correctly, my HTC G1 reports Phone information, battery info and history, and usage statistics.

Take a look at this more general question about dialer codes (aka secret star codes) for reference, too: [Is there an official dialer code resource?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7475/is-there-an-official-dialer-code-resource) There are some good links there for lists of dialer codes and some caveats about using them without adult supervision.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to change my network type also. While it does display all this information, this code is very useful for changing from 4G to 3G to 2G, and all sorts of other options in between.

If you do get this working, look under **phone information**, then *set preferred network type*. You'll have to read up on which type means what for your type of network, but this has allowed me to get better battery life and, at times, better cell service even with a 2G network.