# What are Android's secret telephony codes?

Tags: dialer-codes

What are Android's hidden **Secret Codes**?

There are a bunch of secret codes to access hidden features or perform special actions. They're entered into the dialer and have the following format:

`*#*#<CODE>#*#*`

What are the standard (vanilla) codes and what do various carriers and device makers add?

And how can I find out about them by myself?