# How to see hidden files/folders on android internal storage over USB

Tags: usb, windows

I have a windows 7 pc and a Sony Experia Z android phone. I use a downloader app to download files to the phone, and then hook it up to USB to copy to the computer.

The only problem is sometimes the files+folders do not show. I moved the download folder into DCIM folder (the camera pictures folder, which is always visible), and now the FOLDER appears, but all the files inside it are hidden. How can I get windows to show ABSOLUTELY EVERY file and folder on the phone?

Things I have tried:

- USB Debugging mode.
- A different browser on the windows operating system (Total Commander - Same problem, empty folder)
- Windows explorer settings are set to show all files, folders and hidden system files.
- Resetting the phone

Can someone answer this? I really need a totally working solution. One time I turned on USB debugging and it worked, but today it has not. I need a 100% solution as this is the only way I can download large files from the internet.

I have no router, no 3rd party internet provider and no wifi. I dont know what the android version is, it is just the default one the "Sony xperia Z" came with, and I cannot update the android version, because I dont have wi-fi.

Answer (score 1):

One option may be to go in with [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) this can usually see the file system without much of an issue. So you can look into how to hook it up to your phone (the link above will get you started), and once you are connected copy the files over command line.

Another possibly easier option would be to put a file explorer app on your phone and and transfer the files locally to another visible location on your phones file system.

EDIT:

This may be a bit of a weird one, but if you put this code: `*#*#273283*255*663282*#*#*`

into your dialer, it should give a file copy screen which may give you the desired result.

The code is from [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1468/do-you-know-other-android-keypad-commands-dialer-codes) post.