# How Do I Activate 4G LTE Only On Samsung Galaxy A5(2016)

Tags: samsung, 4g, samsung-galaxy-a5

I use Samsung Galaxy A5(2016) and have just upgraded the firmware to Android 6.0 (Mashmallow). The phone supports 4G but the option to set it there is `LTE/3G/2G (auto connect)` on Network mode.

How do I get the phone to use 4G only?

**P.S.**
I have tried `*#0011#` and have entered `Q0000` as answered [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102077/how-to-safely-activate-lte-on-s4-mini-gt-i9195-running-4-2-2) but it is not working.

Comment: Dial *#2263# and follow the steps as @acejavelin said.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Dialer/Phone application and dial (STAR)#(STAR)#4636#(STAR)#(STAR), then select Phone Information and scroll down to *Set preferred network type* and change the drop-down to LTE only.

Be aware that with few exceptions, like T-Mobile's VoLTE, that in LTE only mode, you will not be able to make or receive phone calls or text messages. 2G/3G/HSPA(+) is required for voice calls and SMS in most GSM/LTE networks.

Also, be careful with using terms like 4G and LTE... depending on your carrier these might be interchangeable, or some carriers use "4G" to mean HSPA+ and "LTE" to mean, well, LTE service, some carriers use "4G" to refer to both/either HSPA+ & LTE, and some others use "4G" to mean only LTE.

In common practice for most users, 2G refers to Edge, 3G refers to GSM, and 4G refers to HSPA/HSPA+ and not LTE service.

Comment: I tried `*#*#4636#*#*` but nothing showed up. It is just there like a phone number to be dialed.

Comment: Hmm... Must be disabled by either Samsung or your carrier. That code usually opens the phone's service menu which allows this to be set.

Comment: Is there any other thing I can try? I really need enable this LTE only...