# Get full list of secret codes in android

Tags: adb, dialer-codes

I was able to run some of settings hidden apps via adb with

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN "com.android.settings"
```

These hidden apps are actually some of the activities runnable via "secret codes". Since secret codes are various and some of them are also vendor/device defined, is there a way to retrieve list of every secret code available on a particular device? Maybe from a manifest, by identifying the receivers, via some adb commands etc.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See this answer in particular https://android.stackexchange.com/a/78607/131553

Comment: Your example does not contain any "secret code" it just starts the app `com.android.settings` using it's package name. You can get a list of all app packages via `adb shell pm list packages`.